# angular 5 reInit owl carousel

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

where i can run function reInit() ngx-owl-carousel ?

I use ngx-owl-carousel module, and use angular 5,

if route change owl- carousel is braked

```
<owl-carousel  #OwlElement class="col-12 col-xs-6 top-15"
             [options]="{
                items: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                loop: true,
                margin:0,
                mouseDrag: true,
                singleItem: true,
                nav:false,
                dotClass: 'dots',
                dotsClass: 'dots-record',
                dots: true,   
                smartSpeed:1000,
                navSpeed: 1000
              }"
             [items]="[record_img]"
             [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'row', 'sliding']">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component:

```
@ViewChild('OwlElement') OwlElement: OwlCarousel 

yourMethod() {
    this.OwlElement.reInit();
}
```